# How do I Join two SQL tables on Multiple date columns

Tags: sql, left-join, case, between

My first table is Called Date_Table this has all the days of the year dating back to January 2020 and goes all the way to 31 Decemeber 2030.The data looks like this:

| Date | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 00:00 | Wed |
| 02/01/2020 00:00 | Thur |

My second table Sales_Table consists of sales stages, each stage has a date assigned when it reaches the stage.
Here is what my data looks like:

| Sale_ID | Enquiry | App Rec | App Passed | Sale Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 00:00 | 02/01/2020 00:00 | 03/01/2020 00:00 | 05/01/2020 00:00 |
| 2 | 02/01/2020 00:00 | 03/01/2020 00:00 | 03/01/2020 00:00 | 05/01/2020 00:00 |

My query is this so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN [Enquiry] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
 END) AS [Total Enquiries],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN [App Rec] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
 END) AS [Apps Received],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN [App Passed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
 END) AS [Apps Passed],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN [Sale Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
 END) AS [Completed Sales]
FROM [Date_Table]
      LEFT JOIN [Sales_Table] ON [Date] Between [Enquiry] AND [App Rec] GROUP BY [Date]
```

This seems to work fine for the first 2 dates but if i add another AND statement in the join I get a parsing of SQL query failed error.

The end report would be a table like this:

| Date | Enquiry | App Rec | App Passed | Sale Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 00:00 | 3 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 02/01/2020 00:00 | 5 | 1 | 11 | 4 |

I tried to add all the dates fields to the left join using BETWEEN and AND
Like this:
`LEFT JOIN [Sales_Table] ON [Date] Between [Enquiry] AND [App Rec] AND [App Passed] AND [Sale Completed]`

This just gave me a parsing error

Comment: You can group by ``Date_Table.Date``

Comment: @ValNik yes sorry i forgot to put that in my post I have it grouped by Date.

Comment: Hi - I have no idea what your LEFT JOIN is supposed to be doing. Please could you update your question with an explanation, expected result, etc.?

Comment: @NickW The purpose of the left join is so that I can bring back the Days from the Date Table even when there was no data in the Sale Table. So for instance if it was a Saturday and no one was working the Report should show 0 for each sale stage. The Table above is what i am looking to produce.Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear but I meant the standalone LEFT JOIN towards the end of your question, not the one in your main query. What is that meant to do and how would it affect your result table? If you want to have rows with a zero count it would be useful if your sample data and resultset showed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example

```
with t as(
select 'Enquiry'event,Enquiry as dt
from Sales_Table
union all
select 'App_Rec',App_Rec
from Sales_Table
union all
select 'App_Passed',App_Passed
from Sales_Table
union all
select 'Sale_Completed',Sale_Completed
from Sales_Table
)
,totals as(
select dt
   ,sum(case when event='Enquiry' then 1 else 0 end)Enquiry
   ,sum(case when event='App_Rec' then 1 else 0 end)App_Rec
   ,sum(case when event='App_Passed' then 1 else 0 end)App_Passed
   ,sum(case when event='Sale_Completed' then 1 else 0 end)Sale_Completed
from t
group by dt
)
select *
from Date_Table d
left join totals t on t.dt=d.date
```

Output is

| Date | Day | dt | Enquiry | App_Rec | App_Passed | Sale_Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Wedn | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | Thur | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | Frid | 2020-01-03 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 | Satu | null | null | null | null | null |
| 2020-01-05 | Sund | 2020-01-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

with test data

```
create table Date_table(Date date,  Day varchar(10));
insert into Date_Table ([date]) values 
 ('2020-01-01')
,('2020-01-02')
,('2020-01-03')
,('2020-01-04')
,('2020-01-05')
;
update Date_Table
  set [Day]=left(datename(dw,[date]),4)
;
create table Sales_Table (Sale_ID int,Enquiry date,App_Rec date, App_Passed date, Sale_Completed date);
insert into Sales_Table values
 (1,'2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-05')
,(2,'2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-03','2020-01-05')
;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D-wlwWLT)